# cannot find tag library descriptor for spring framework in maven eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

The following three lines at the top of documents.jsp throw "cannot find tag library descriptor for ..." errors in the spring framework application from [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/), which uses eclipse and maven:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"  prefix="spring"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

My understanding is that the maven plugin for eclipse should manage the download of these libraries automatically, so I checked to make sure that the following are included in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<properties>
  <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

So how do I fix my application to enable the required dependencies to be available?  I want to avoid having to do it manually, because I was under the impression that maven should manage this.  Is there some way that I need to manipulate maven?  The application apparently worked when it was tested for the tutorial.

### EDIT:

I converted my eclipse project to a maven project and then right clicked on the eclipse project and chose Maven>Update Project.  This did nothing to fix the error that still remains from my original posting above, but it also added the following new error:

```
Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B
```

Which is now thrown by the second line of pom.xml, which reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

### SECOND EDIT:

When I try to run as..run on server, I get the following error in a dialog box:

```
'Publishing to Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost...' has encountered a problem.

Error reading file D:\mypath\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.0.1B\jta-1.0.1B.jar
D:\mypath\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.0.1B\jta-1.0.1B.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I even set "update Maven projects on startup" in Window>preferences>Maven and then closed and restarted eclipse, but the problem persists.

Comment: Are you sure this is failing for spring and not for the core taglibs? Could you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: @benjamin.d I have just been viewing the code in eclipse, so there was no stack trace.  When I read your comment, I tried run as...run on server, and got the error dialog box shown in my second edit to my original posting, which I just added above.

Comment: As long as it's on the project's Java Build Path *somehow*, it'll be found.  It could be that Maven's method of updating the project doesn't trigger the right refresh. Try Closing and then Opening the project to force it.

Answer (score 1):

I passed for this same issue where I receive the message

`"cannot find tag library descriptor for ..."`

I solved putting spring-webmvc inside of my war. This error happened when spring-webmvc were in server folder.

I suggest you see how do you're packaging your war.

Comment: Thank you.  I may end up resorting to that.  But I should be able to run as...run on server from eclipse.  Bundling it into a war every time I need to run a test during development would become very time consuming.

Comment: @CodeMed if the problem is the unit tests you can add the line -Dmaven.test.skip=true that skis the unit tests, in the proper Eclipse you have the option to skip tests from maven

Comment: The problem was that my pom.xml had different version numbers for the jstl and taglibs dependencies.  One was 1.1.2 and the other was 1.2.  When I changed them both to the same version number, things worked properly, and I was able to do run as...run on server from within eclipse. But thank you for following up.